# Visual Studio new project command possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, project

I recently started working in VS and every time I start to do my projects I need the same set of files.

For ex : (note this is visual c++ , working only with c++ stuff)

1. Win32 Console Application
2. Empty Project
3. I need to create in this project 3 files, main.cpp , unit.h, unit.cpp

Its kinda annoying to do this step like 20 times a day and I need to know if its possible to create a macro (command) that does this for me?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Creating Visual Studio Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx)

Comment: _"if its possible to create a macro(command)"_ Yes, it is. Did you try yourself already?

Comment: Why are you making 20 new projects a day?  That's something I do like once every few months...  Even in college it was once a week!

Comment: You could always make your base project in a folder and copy the folder and start from that.

Comment: Good question, and Alex K gave a good answer.  This might also help: [Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Project System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961.aspx)